# Database Vs XML

Tags: xml-parsing

I am having 63MB of XML file. I am using MXML for searching and all. I just want to know searching of data in XML is faster or if I dump this data in DB and then search will be faster? All this I have to do in C.

Answer (score 1):

there is no question . putting it intoi DB will be a LOT faster

Comment: depending on how the data is structured, it may be difficult to fit it into a table schema, though

Answer (score 0):

Using XML would render your application more portable and a database would make the data access faster. A lot.